# Issue in Importing Magento Database

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to import magento database that i previously exported and saved in my system but now when i'm trying to import it gives following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that...
>
> I have tried importing it with command line but that also did'nt solve my issue and.

```
> CREATE TABLE `cmg_admin_assert` (   `assert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT
> NULL COMMENT 'Assert ID',   `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
> COMMENT AS `Assert Type`,   `assert_data` text COMMENT 'Assert Data' )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Assert Table';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid, try this one.

```
CREATE TABLE `cmg_admin_assert` (   `assert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT
 NULL COMMENT 'Assert ID',   `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
 COMMENT 'Assert Type',   `assert_data` text COMMENT 'Assert Data' )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT 'Admin Assert Table';
```

View working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b80385/1).